# What is RESTful way to access resources attached to different resource

Tags: python, rest, flask

My data mode looks like

`User` has **many** `Transaction`. Both `User` and `Transaction` are different tables in database
I have `REST` endpoints as

**User Endpoint**

```
GET /users/uuid # to get information about specific user
PUT /users/uuid # update information of a specific user
```

**Transaction Endpoint**

```
GET /transactions/uuid # get a specific transaction
GET /transactions/user_uuid # get all transactions of a specific user
GET /transactions/user_uuid/yyyy # get all transactions of a specific user in year yyyy
GET /transactions/user_uuid/yyyy/mm # get all transactions of a specific user in year yyyy, month mm
GET /transactions/user_uuid/yyyy/mm/dd # get all transactions of a specific user in year yyyy, month mm and day dd
```

- My question is since `transactions` will always be attached with `User` resource, does it make sense to have a different endpoint for them?
- What is recommended to access transactions of user? the one posted above? or something like

> ```
> GET /users/uuid/transactions # all transactions for a user
> GET /users/uuid/transactions/yyyy # all transactions for a user for year yyyy
> GET /users/uuid/transactions/yyyy/mm # all transactions for a user for year yyyy, month mm
> GET /users/uuid/transactions/yyyy/mm/dd # all transactions for a user for year yyyy, month mm and day dd
> ```

I am confused at this moment as to which one is better.

Thank you

Comment: It really depends your needs

Comment: There is no true definition of what makes something "RESTful". Therefore, we cannot say which of these options is "better". When you try to objectively get into such discussions, it ends up coming down to ultimately how your API will end up being used. Sometimes, it just really doesn't matter. You might even end up using both ways. You're fearing that you're missing out on something that might negatively impact your product. However, your main enemy here, IMO, is overanalysis.

Comment: Thank you @MarkHildreth, I believe I hear you, I would try to expose API as per best use case and refactor later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always access `transactions` in the context of an user it makes sense for me your second approach since as you say and user has many `transactions`, with your first approach the url design can be quite confusing because its not clear that the date part references the `transactions` and not the user resource. In the other hand if you want to read all `transactions` for all users, can make sense that you have two endpoints for `transactions`

```
GET /transactions/ # reads all transactions for all users
GET /transactions/yyyy # reads all trasnsaction for all users with date 
GET /users/uuid/transactions # reads all transaction for a particular user
GET /users/uuid/transactions/yyyy # reads all transactions for a particular user with date
```

Comment: Thanks @Pitxon, I guess your are right here, I should start with the second approach since it makes more sense as per the sue case right now